# React nested routes doesn't update through Link

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4

It's worth mentioning that I am using `redux`, and `ApolloProvider`.
The following are the paths:

- `/` index
- `/tickets` views tickets
- `/tickets` creates new tickets

`index.js` entry point

```
const store = createStore(/* Redux reducer */);

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // emitted states...
        // define apollo client this.state = {client: new ApolloClient...}
    }

   // emitted functions...

    render() {
        return (
            <ApolloProvider client={this.state.client}>
                <Root {...(this.props)} {...(this.state)}/>
            </ApolloProvider>
        )
    }
}

const ReduxConnector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><ReduxConnector/></Provider>, document.getElementById("react-loader"));
```

`root.js` Main class with logic and routing

```
class Root extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    // emitted functions...
    render() {
        if (this.props.authorized) {
            return (
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Fragment>
                        <Header/>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
                            <Route path='/tickets' component={Tickets}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </Fragment>
                </BrowserRouter>
            )
        } else {
            return <Login/>;
        }
    }
}
export default Root;
```

`tickets.js` Provides tickets routing

```
class Tickets extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (<BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/create`} component={Create}/>
                <Route exact path={`${this.props.match.path}`} component={View}/>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>);
    }
}

export default Tickets;
```

Now finally, the partial `header.js` component loaded in `root.js`

```
<Link to={"/"}>Homepage</Link>
<Link to={"/tickets"}>View tickets</Link>
<Link to={"/tickets/create"}>Create a ticket</Link>
```

The deal is, when navigating through the address bar, all paths render correctly. Through the header Link only navigating between `/` and either `/tickets` or `/tickets/create` works, but navigating between `/tickets` and `/tickets/create` doesn't update the DOM. I have tried placing using withRouter at `const ReduxConnector = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));` but couldn't quite figure it out to be of any use.

What are the possibilities for such behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `BrowserRouter` component from your `Tickets` component. You only need a single instance of it to be rendered in the tree above any use of other React-Router components. Repeating it lower in the tree will break things.